# Not getting my wire transfer till 15 days

Tags: india, international-transfer, salary, israel

My money is not credited where my office is released the money on 4th Jan. Its exactly 12 working days gone but still I am not sure what is the problem.

It is a wire transfer from Israel to India through correspondent bank swift code.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Wire transfers should not take longer than one or max two business days. Anything else is a sign of issues (remember though that business days and bank holidays are different in different countries).
Depending on the receiving banks software, it could take another day to show up in online banking.

After that, you should contact the *sending* bank to find out about the status. They are responsible for tracing the money and verifying where it went or where it is stuck.

This could be an intermediary that is missing some data, or it could be a government agency that is verifying something (and they take as long as they take), or it could be some data you gave were incorrect (or read incorrectly), and it went to the wrong recipient. Either way, the sending bank must be able to trace it for you.
Typically, they are reluctant to put effort in it (they don't get paid any more), and try to tell you to 'wait a bit more'. It is up to you to push them to start the tracing, when you think it is time.